# Display sub-category depended on selected category with related entries

Tags: categories

I am not even sure, I can explain it.

1. I have a several sections, but I'll go with "Products" section. Than I have category group called "Filter". I'd like to use only this category group for all sections. ( if there is a better approach/start in this step, include it in your answer ).
2. When page "Products" is loaded, there should be a category list of top level categories only + entries related to "Products".
3. When a top level category link "Cat1" is clicked at "site.com/products", a page "site.com/products/cat1" should load. On "site.com/products/cat1" page should be a category list of top level categories + sub level categories + entries related to sub level category.
4. Then, when a sub level category link "cat1.1" is clicked, a page "site.com/products/cat1/cat1.1" should load with the same scenario as in previous step.
5. We will carry on up to, when we have url formed like this: "site.com/products/cat1/cat1.1/cat1.1.1/entry-title"

I hope, you have some image about, What I'm trying to draw here.
I only see this achievable through sections and categories.

Comment: You said there are multiple sections - so to be clear you want this same site structure to also work on other areas of your site besides /products/...? E.g. there could be a /services/cat1/cat1.1/ URL as well?

Comment: Exactly. This question relates to my other question you recently edited "how do I only display descendant list of categories..." . It's actually my progress for this question if I may call that.